# Swift: Fetching photos from Flickr always fetch the same photos

Tags: ios, json, swift, flickr

I am writing an app for a Udacity portfolio project which would fetch photos from Flickr and display in a collectionView. When a button is pressed, it will refresh the photos in the collectionView. However I am unable to get new sets of photos despite the fact that the search parameters have different page number after every call. My code as follows:

```
 func getPhotosURLFromFlickr(_ lat: AnyObject, lon: AnyObject, _ completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL: @escaping (_ imageURL: [String]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        taskForGetPagesFromFlickr(lat, lon: lon) { (parameters, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, error as NSError)
            } else {

                if let parameters = parameters {
                    print(parameters)
                    self.taskForGetPhotos(parameters, { (imageURLArray, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, error as NSError)
                        } else {
                            if let imageURLArray = imageURLArray {
                                completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(imageURLArray, nil)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

 func taskForGetPagesFromFlickr(_ lat: AnyObject, lon: AnyObject, _ completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL: @escaping (_ parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        let parameters = [
            Constants.ParametersKey.Method: Constants.Methods.PhotoSearch as AnyObject,
            Constants.ParametersKey.FlickrAPIKey : Constants.APIInfo.APIKey as AnyObject,
            Constants.ParametersKey.Format: Constants.ParametersValues.JSON as AnyObject,
            Constants.ParametersKey.NoJSONCallback: Constants.ParametersValues.DisableJSONCallback as AnyObject,
            Constants.ParametersKey.PerPage: Constants.ParametersValues.Fifteen as AnyObject,
            Constants.ParametersKey.Extras: Constants.ParametersValues.MediumURL as AnyObject]

        var parametersWithCoord = parameters
        parametersWithCoord[Constants.ParametersKey.lat] = lat
        parametersWithCoord[Constants.ParametersKey.lon] = lon

        let url = flickrURLFromParameters(parametersWithCoord)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, error as NSError)
            } else {
                self.convertDataWithCompletionHandler(data!, completionHandlerForConvertData: { (results, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, error as NSError)
                    } else {
//                        print(results)
                        guard let photosDict = results?["photos"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "NoPhotosFound"]
                            completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, NSError(domain: "NoPhotosFound", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
                            return
                        }

                        guard let pages = photosDict[Constants.ParametersKey.Pages] as? Int else {
                            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "NoPagesFound"]
                            completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, NSError(domain: "NoPagesFound", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
                            return
                        }

                        let randomPageIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pages)))
                        var searchParameters = parametersWithCoord
                        searchParameters[Constants.ParametersKey.Page] = randomPageIndex as AnyObject?
                        print("Number of pages: \(pages)")
                        print("Random page index: \(randomPageIndex)")
                        completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(searchParameters, nil)
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func taskForGetPhotos(_ parameters: [String: AnyObject], _ completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL: @escaping (_ imageURL: [String]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        let url = flickrURLFromParameters(parameters)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        print(url)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, error as NSError)
            } else {
                self.convertDataWithCompletionHandler(data!, completionHandlerForConvertData: { (results, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, error as NSError)
                    } else {
//                        print(results)
                        guard let photosDict = results?["photos"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "NoPhotosFound"]
                            completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, NSError(domain: "NoPhotosFound", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
                            return
                        }

                        guard let photosArray = photosDict["photo"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
                            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "NoPhotosArrayFound"]
                            completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(nil, NSError(domain: "NoPhotosArray", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
                            return
                        }

                        var imageURLArray: [String] = []

                        if photosArray.count != 0 {
                            for pics in photosArray {
                                guard let imageURLString = pics[Constants.ParametersValues.MediumURL] as? String else {
                                    print("NoImageURLString Found")
                                    return
                                }

                                imageURLArray.append(imageURLString)
                            }
                        }
                        print("ImageURLArray : \(imageURLArray)")
                        completionHandlerForGetPhotosURL(imageURLArray, nil)
                    }
                })
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

When my refresh button is tapped, the above set of networking code runs, and if I tap the button twice, my print statements are as such:

> FETCHING NEW COLLECTION... 
>   Number of items 0 Number of pages: 5712
>   Random page index: 490
>   https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?page=490&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&lon=103.7940514843148&api_key=*APIKEY*&per_page=15&lat=1.411935988414726&extras=url_m&nojsoncallback=1
>   ImageURLArray :
>   ["https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2059/32542810620_37312d07c9.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2330/32102051403_46e30a5eec.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2104/32529883860_17558a0acf.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2595/32778162441_db4a98d3cd.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2466/32087213853_257910d32d.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2029/32891916665_2d2d177e71.jpg",
>   "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3685/32878992915_38baaf513e.jpg",
>   "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/631/32062787803_ed58defea5.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2332/32873171215_c807db5364.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2788/32825584606_7d2bff507c.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2479/32052120503_1317f70f1a.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2909/32023922664_d276f52369.jpg",
>   "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/376/32023912434_9b89fc3d7b.jpg",
>   "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/455/32018845514_22681384ae.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2833/32734093131_0e8da333f4.jpg"]
>
> FETCHING NEW COLLECTION... 
>   Number of items 0 Number of pages: 5712
>   Random page index: 5383
>   https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?page=5383&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&lon=103.7940514843148&api_key=*APIKEY*&per_page=15&lat=1.411935988414726&extras=url_m&nojsoncallback=1
>   ImageURLArray :
>   ["https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2059/32542810620_37312d07c9.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2330/32102051403_46e30a5eec.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2104/32529883860_17558a0acf.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2595/32778162441_db4a98d3cd.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2466/32087213853_257910d32d.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2029/32891916665_2d2d177e71.jpg",
>   "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3685/32878992915_38baaf513e.jpg",
>   "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/631/32062787803_ed58defea5.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2332/32873171215_c807db5364.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2788/32825584606_7d2bff507c.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2479/32052120503_1317f70f1a.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2909/32023922664_d276f52369.jpg",
>   "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/376/32023912434_9b89fc3d7b.jpg",
>   "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/455/32018845514_22681384ae.jpg",
>   "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2833/32734093131_0e8da333f4.jpg"]

You would realise that despite that the search page is different for both times, but the imageURLArray is actually the same. I can't seem to identify the reason why.

Some help is much appreciated pls, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I manage to solve my problem. I limit the randomPageIndex with a maximum number of 100 and it successfully refreshes the page.

Perhaps Flickr has some maximum search pages which I may not be aware of.